# Same name for form fields & database table fields?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, forms

Is it considered bad practice to give HTML form names the same name as table field names? I am building some dynamic sql insert queries, and at present I am using some regexp's to change the names to the relevant database fields on the basis I feel it may be insecure otherwise, what are your opinions?

Comment: bit hard to get around having "firstname" in both a table and a form. Names are irrelevant, as long as you're not roundtripping those field names through the form, opening yourself to all sorts of sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a function to do `INSERT` queries for me, and it depends on that fact. It takes the `$_POST` variable names and `INSERT`s them into their corresponding columns.

As said in the comment on the OP, it doesn't matter, and in most cases, saves you time going back to remember if you used `first_name,` `firstname,` or `first.`

Also, keep in mind that your users will never see the database column names, and they will only see the form names if they view the source. Therefore, there's not much to worry about!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you reduce the coding you need to do. Even though it looks like a vulnerability, what most important thing is to check the values coming from the users for malicious data. I don't think it could be harmful since knowing which DB fields you are using doesn't give much to the hackers. They still need to hack into the DB server to access your data.

Comment: To elaborate on this, everyone knows that a table will have an `id` field, and one storing users will have a `password,` `salt,` and `name` column. So don't worry

Answer (score 0):

The names should be readable enough for you to read, and yet "unpredictable" (with a lack of a better term) enough for an attacker not being able to guess the private parts.

Form names don't really matter, but a good name for a password field would be `the_users_password` or `passphrase_for_account`.

Comment: Why would `the_users_password` be any more secure than `password`?

Comment: @David: Because an attacker will have a harder time guessing it. It's little security, as if he got this far, he'll be able to get the table's schema, but still...

Comment: Well hopefully he isn't storing passwords in plaintext in the password column! I understand what you're saying, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is easier to remember and maintain if form name and field name are the same
2. I often make one field different form name vs field name
3. Clean the $post and implement XSS handling