# Is there any security issue in using same name for textbox and table field?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, codeigniter

Am using the same name for my table field and input text-box name in front end. Is it a good practice and is there any security issue here:

Table userdetails:

```
userdetails_firstname   varchar(255)
userdetails_lastname    varchar(255)
userdetails_username    varchar(255)
userdetails_password    varchar(255)
```

My html form:-

```
<input type="text" name = "userdetails_firstname"/>
<input type="text" name = "userdetails_lastname"/>
<input type="text" name = "userdetails_username"/>
<input type="text" name = "userdetails_password"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer your question. We can't audit your code's secutiry without code.

Comment: No, it's fine to do it like that. You should be concerned with what goes into the database (sanitize perhaps, but be sure to use prepared statements!!) and what goes out (use something like `htmlspecialchars()` on output from it)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for the reply ,what i was thinking is like , can some one guess my table name or fields and dump database and all.

Comment: If you use prepared statements, it doesn't really matter. No need to obscure it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same name for form fields & database table fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704761/same-name-for-form-fields-database-table-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing critical as long as you are using PDO and prepare() to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: You can use mysqli too it you want, but what matters is that you use prepared statements **with placeholders**.